# Forcing XmlWriter to use 'invalid' characters

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlwriter

I am converting an EDIFACT file to an OUIUBL file (technically just an XML file), **(Essentially I'm creating an XML file)** and I want to have prefixes in my tags like "cac:" for instance. E.g.

```
<cac:Tax>
    <cbc:Amount>500.00</cbc:Amount>
</cac:Tax>
```

I am using an XmlWriter to create the xml, essentially doing it like so:

```
writer.WriteStartDocument()
writer.WriteStartElement("cac:Tax")
writer.WriteElementString("Amount", "500.00")
writer.WriteEndElement()
writer.WriteStartDocument()
```

But I get an error saying that ":" is an invalid character. How do I force it to use it anyway? I have tried the following

```
Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
settings.Indent = True
settings.CheckCharacters = false
```

And I've also tried setting a prefix and namespace for the startElement:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("cac", "Tax", Nothing)
```

But neither of those seemed to work... Well setting the prefix did, but only if I also declare a namespace, and I don't want that.

I want it to format it like xml but neglect any syntactic differences :)

Comment: Take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx

Or  http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_schema.asp

"cac:" is the schema.

Comment: @Malcor: Technically cac: is NOT the schema, but rather the namespace prefix that might inherit a schema.

Comment: @JaggenSWE you are completely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Malcor and @JaggenSWE I found out that I had to declare the namespaces

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","cbc", Nothing,"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","cac", Nothing,"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")
```

Not only did this do the trick, it is also exactly how you're supposed to do it, I just didn't realize at first.